# Android differentiate assets for 320x480 and 480x800

Tags: android, screen-resolution, dpi

I've read the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about different densities and resolutions, but cannot find how to use different assets for the screens with the same density? For example, 320x480 and 480x800 use the same mdpi, but obviously it would be better not to scale graphics programatically and use pre-scaled assets. Is it possible to force application use different graphics for different resolutions with the same dpi?

Android version 2.2+, normal and large screens

Comment: Did you read [this section](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) which describes coding for different sizes in Android 3.2+ ? "Android now allows you to specify your layout resources based on the width and/or height that's actually available for your application's layout, specified in dp units."

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing on normal screen (320x480)is in mdpi and  (480x800) is in  hdpi

Comment: @DheereshSingh if you look through the google link, 480x800 and 480x854 are mdpi Large screen

Comment: @Sam actually, I want to support 2.2+ range

Comment: The compatibility library allows you to use later APIs in earlier versions.

Comment: And 480x800 (through that link) is in the table under ldpi, mdpi AND hdpi. Dpi is the ratio of resolution to screen size, certain parts of apps can be placed / designed using density, but I agree images being sized perfectly builds a nicer looking ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section of the Developers Guide you should see is [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

If you want to use different drawables for different-sized screens at the same dpi, then implement layouts and drawables in different size and/or display-width buckets.

The Guide tells you in what order to name the resource-path qualifiers.  Or, you can let the XML file creation wizard in Eclipse do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad idea to try to target every possible resolution. There are literally hundreds (thousands?) of different resolutions on Android devices (not to mention future resolutions).

If at all possible, use mdpi, hdpi, etc. You may want to compose your image assets. For example, on splash screens, the background image and your logo will probably be separate images that you can compose using the Drawable framework.